# How to make a portable program in C# Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, windows

Portable means the program runs immediately and doesn't ask to be added in "Programs and Features" of Windows.

I only know in Visual Studio C# 2015 to press Build->Publish, and publish the program to a setup.exe file with a folder near, and when I run setup.exe it adds itself to Programs and Features...

The program is a Windows Forms Application program.

Comment: You can take a program exe file with all dependent dll files and just run the program exe file without installing anything, build your application with release configurations, and copy the .exe from your bin folder

Comment: Provided .NET is installed at the target, which it usually is..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the build configuration to: Release

Build the solution.

Zip the files in the bin\Release folder.

Unzip on another PC.

Run the exe file.

Answer (score 0):

It should work too if you just give the .exe file from the release folder to the user.